# What is the correct way to predict ROC for logistic regression with ridge?

Tags: r, glm, glmnet, auc

I am trying to get AUC value from the logistic regression for 2 classes classification problem. Response of this data is factor of 1 (terrible) and 2 (great).

The model is built as follow:

```
fit.ridge = glmnet(xmat, as.numeric(train$response), alpha = 0, family="binomial")
```

During the prediction step, I found 2 ways to achieve ROC using package `pROC`. However, these 2 ways give different results:

```
xmat = model.matrix(response ~ ., data = train)[, -1]
```

Note: bestlam.ridge = best lambda value from cv.glmnet

Way 1)

```
pred = predict(fit.ridge, s = bestlam.ridge, newx = xmat, type="response")
auc = roc(as.numeric(train$response), as.numeric(pred))$auc
```

Way 2)

```
pred = predict(fit.ridge, s = bestlam.ridge, newx = xmat, type="response")
print(range(pred))
pred_bool = rep('bad', length(pred))
pred_bool[pred > 0.5] = 'good'
table(train$quality, pred_bool)
roc(as.numeric(train$quality), as.numeric(as.factor(pred_bool)))$auc
```

Way 1 gives about 0.1 higher AUC than Way 2 (and has the same AUC values as in `cv.glmnet` when I used `type.measure="auc"`).

But Way 2 looks like a valid way to go for the classification problem.

Please let me know which way is the correct AUC in this case?

Comment: Way 2 is strange - you would use this approach to calculate specific statistics at a specific threshold - in this case you chose 0.5, however, it appears as if you are using this one threshold and then trying to calculate the auc , which doesnt make sense. auc is a measure evaluated at many thresholds

Comment: Thank you sir @user20650 :) I spent my whole day looking into this problem.